# homebrew stopped working after MacOS update

Tags: homebrew, ruby

I updated my MacBook Pro to Monterey (version 12.6.4).

Now when I enter any `brew` command on the command line, I get an exception:

```
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/version.rb:366:in `initialize': Version value must be a string; got a NilClass () (TypeError)
from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/os/mac/version.rb:23:in `initialize'
from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/os/mac.rb:18:in `new'
from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/os/mac.rb:18:in `version'
from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/os/mac.rb:52:in `prerelease?'
from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/os.rb:19:in `<module:OS>'
from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/os.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/portable-ruby/2.3.7/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/portable-ruby/2.3.7/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/global.rb:26:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb:21:in `require_relative'
from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb:21:in `<main>'
```

My `ruby --version` says *ruby 2.6.10p210 (2022-04-12 revision 67958) [universal.x86_64-darwin21]*

I also tried the `brew` command by setting a Ruby 2.4.2 in front of the PATH search order, but same effect.

Digging into the code (os.rb), I found the definition of the constant

```
::OS_VERSION = ENV["HOMEBREW_OS_VERSION"]
```

and I don't have defined this environment variable, neither do I have defined HOMEBREW_OSX_VERSION. I think this could explain the NilClass exception, but I am not aware that I ever had this environment variable, and `brew` worked fine before.

Any idea of what is going on?

UPDATE: I also tried the suggestion on [the homebrew page](https://docs.brew.sh/Common-Issues), i.e. doing a `git clean -f` in `/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Contributions/examples`, but there is no `Contributions` directory, and a clean in the `Homebrew` base directory did not help either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if it helps, but my experience with Homebrew Ruby-version problems after macOS updates is that this has usually solved them:

```bash
cd $(brew --repo)
git pull origin master
```

I.e. in the Homebrew base directory, completely reload Homebrew.

Comment: This worked indeed. Of course I had to do this in a shell with admin privileges, otherwise `git pull` would not have been possible.

Comment: Same issue. This worked perfectly.